# How do I properly align ImageViews on top of one another?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently trying to make a simple tic-tac-toe game, consisting of ImageViews on top of the board (also an ImageView). However, when I run the app and click on a tile, the picture appears out of place, even though it seems I had lined up the ImageViews correctly.

What I did was I set each original tile to a blank square, and then when the user clicks on a tile, it would change to either "X" or "O," depending on whose turn it was.

I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with dpi scaling on different devices, but I'm not quite sure how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've included an image of my problem below:

[image]

Comment: How did you set the grid up?  Are you using a gridLayout?  a ConstraintLayout?

Comment: use `ConstraintLayout` and `Frame` instead of `ImageView` and insert `ImageView` inside each `Frame`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an image to display the grid, I would suggest to use XML views.

Horizontal line:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

Vertical Line:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

And constraint them between the images.